# What's the best way to manage Resque jobs on per user basis?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, resque

I'm migrating from Delayed_jobs to Resque and I have difficulties finding the best way to handle those cases:

1. A user can NOT add twice the same command to the list of jobs (e.g. "export all my data"). Only one export command at a time. For other it's fine to have many (e.g. send emails)
2. Some jobs should not run for more than 5 minutes, while other are allowed to run for 30 minutes. In both cases, I'd like to have a time-out in case process is blocked or is not completed on time.
3. Can add jobs to start in a few days
4. Inform the user on all their current & future jobs.
5. Can cancel some jobs (current and future) for the user
6. Keep ability to have different lists (mostly for priorities / slow and fast tasks)

I looked at resque-status and it seems like it provides the low level query, but I would still need to do my per user job management.

Suggestions on best way to handle this?

Comment: Why not sidekiq? It is a bit more capable than resque and is a lot faster.

Comment: Price is prohibitive for a company my size

Comment: There's a free version.

Comment: Batches, which seems to solve my problem are not

Comment: That they aren't, yes.

Comment: If it was a one price fee, I'd go for it even 3 times as expensive, but a subscription where they can change the price any time and grab you by the balls, no thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the Resque plugins page? It looks like there are plugins covering many of your requirements. https://github.com/resque/resque/wiki/plugins

Comment: P.S. Timeouts should be handled by the jobs themselves. Take a look at the handy Timeout class in the standard library: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html

Comment: I did read Resque plug in page. I use resque-scheduler and resque-status, they change syntax/usage of resque default jobs. The trick is to know the combination will work nicely and and that each gem is properly done (esp regarding dependency version) and well maintained. I can't imagine I'm the only one with those requirements so I'm thinking there is a consensus about what combo to use.